# Deep Learning Hardware (PC/Ubuntu)

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard, cooling

I have checked a few questions here regarding the GPU and bought the 1080Ti.
Now I am trying to figure out the rest of the configuration and it should be below 1000$.

I have seen that `i5-8600K` sounds like a good option and I would like to go with 8th generation. However, now I am stuck with choosing the appropriate motherboard and cooling units.

In my country I have available:
`GIGABYTE Z370 AORUS GAMING 3 REV.1.0` and `ASUS ROG STRIX Z370-H GAMING` which i have available for `230$` and `280$` respectively.

I am also considering `Gigabyte Z370 HD3` which is a cheaper option `150$`.

Please note, that I do not need anything shiny (RGB LEDs etc.) but single PCI x16 is required. On top of this, I will need a suggestion for cooling.

Also, it would be great if someone could tell me which boards play nicely with Linux (Ubuntu).

Any suggestions are more than welcome, even which brand seems better to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should go with the Gigabyte Z370 HD3, since it is the cheapest option meeting your requirements.** However, if your configuration requires a lot of RAM which you didn't mention, the most expensive option (ASUS configuration) offers 4 slots of RAM. According to [the intel spec sheet for the i5-8600k](https://ark.intel.com/products/126685/Intel-Core-i5-8600K-Processor-9M-Cache-up-to-4_30-GHz), the maximum supported memory per slot is 32 gb. It's up to you whether you feel you will need more than 32gb of RAM in the future.

It's worth mentioning the GIGABYTE option has 2 m.2 SATA slots meaning you could potentially have two m.2 sata SSDs (The Samsung 970 Evo's are an affordable high performance option.)

**Other recommendations**

I took the liberty of checking your location on your Stack exchange profile which states you are from Montenegro, and a cursory google search tells me that you are not officially a part of the EU. This makes recommending you specific hardware not subject to additional shipping or tax import costs very difficult, however; [here is an exhaustive list from pc part picker sorted by price that meets or exceeds your stated requirements](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/motherboard/#s=30&X=0,100000&J=0&K=1,10&E=1,4&N=4,16&T=2048,65536&L=4&h=1,8&sort=price&xcx=0&a=1,5). You can cross-check the prices you find there with your local purveyors. The site will also let you double check your builds for compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Sorry about the delay. Finally, after discussing it with reseller I have purchased the `ASUS ROG STRIX Z370-H GAMING`. Resseler told me that since the parts will be under constant load it is better to have "overclocking" ready setup for better life duration.